# SwiftData Nested Parent/Child Object Locking Issue

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm trying to process a json file that looks something like this:

```
    {
      "parents": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Parent #1",
          "child1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Child #1"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Parent #2",
          "child1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Child #1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

My SwiftData models are structured like:

```
@Model
class Parent: Decodable, Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    
    @Relationship
    var child: Child?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case child
    }
    
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.child = try container.decodeIfPresent(Child.self, forKey: .child)
        
    }
}

@Model
class Child: Decodable, Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
    }
    
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

I'm processing it like so:

```
private func handleData(filePath: URL ) {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: filePath)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Parent.self, from: data)
        
        jsonData.records.forEach { record in
            context.insert(record)
        }
        
        // This throws a error when multiple parents share the same child
        context.save()
        
        catch {
            print("ERROR!")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if the child object between the two parents overlaps (e.g. it's the same object) and I save them together I run into a locking issue. Is there a better solution for saving? I read through the CoreData merge resolution but I couldn't figure out how to make that work in the SwiftData framework.

Alternatively, if I wanted to lookup the ID of the "Child" to see if it already exists when the parent is decoded, should I do that within the decoder?

Comment: Do you download this when the user views something or download it when the app starts?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Okay I'll give it a try. Does the relationship have to be defined on the child? I don't have any reason to traverse backwards (one to many relationship, where the parent will have thousands of children).

Comment: @malhal Downloaded in the background when the app is opened.

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77495216/9223839) for a possible solution to this issue.